# Linker error in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, compilation, linker-errors, suse

Our machine was in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4 until when we recently moved to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3.

Our C++ tools were compiling without any problem on SuSe 11. But when we compile the tools in SuSe 12, we are having below linker error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../libXm.so when searching for -lXm                                                                                                                   
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lXm                                                      
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../libXt.so when searching for -lXt                                                                                                                   
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lXt                                                      
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../libX11.so when searching for -lX11                                                                                                                 
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

After some exploration, I came to know that compilation is successful with 64 bit. But I want the binaries in 32 bit.

I know that the linker is searching for the file `libXm.so`, `libXt.so`, `libX11.so` but unable to find the right file.

The following page from SuSe tells that there is no support of x86 from SuSe12 onwards: https://www.suse.com/products/server/download

When I checked those files in SuSe 11 SP4, it was available as:

```
/usr/lib/libXm.so -> libXm.so.4.0.1
/usr/lib/libXt.so -> libXt.so.6.0.0
/usr/lib/libX11.so -> libX11.so.6.2.0
```

In SuSe 12, these `.so` are not available under `/usr/lib`. But `libXm.so.4.*` or `libXt.so.6.*` or `libX11.so.6.*` are present under `/usr/lib`. Its only the softlink from these files to `.so` are missing (not available).

So how do I overcome this problem in this environment?

Comment: opensSUSE docs: [32-Bit and 64-Bit Applications in a 64-Bit System Environment](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha.64bit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try `zypper se -snt package 32bit | grep devel`, and see what X11 related devel packages are missing. Most of them are in the SDK. But as I note just now, developing X11 for 32bit may not be supported anymore. Please check the ReleaseNotes for SLE12 regarding this topic.